# My DLLImport works well at Winform Application but got Exception at Asp.net WebFormApplication

Tags: asp.net, winforms, dllimport

My `DLLImport` (A Delphi DLL) works well with a Winform Application but I get an Exception with my ASP.net WebForm Application (on IIS 7).

Can someone please tell me why and how to deal with it?

```
[DllImport("DLL_YINLIAN_INTERFACE.dll", EntryPoint = "YL_SetParam", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        static extern int YL_SetParam(int iParamIndex, byte[] ucParamBuffer);
```

Here is the Exception while debugging:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException (0x80004005): 
   External component has thrown an exception.
   at JFTHardAPI.SandTran.YL_SetParam(Int32 iParamIndex, Byte[] ucParamBuffer)
```

Answer (score 0):

`SEHException` are thrown from Unmanaged code. 
Use the debugger: `Debug > Exceptions`, **turn on** the `Thrown flag for Win32 Exceptions`.

Also, try changing the unmanaged function to use `StdCall`. `Check the calling convention` on both Managed and UnManaged sides. Using the wrong calling convention can affect the state of the call stack. [image]